# JQ - removing duplicates using unique_by

Tags: json, unique, jq

I am trying to remove the duplicates from the following json by `id`
Here is the json:

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "name": "validation-of-art",
      "id": "12",
      "status": "passed",
      "duration": 4740302
    },
    {
      "name": "validation-of-art",
      "id": "12",
      "status": "passed",
      "duration": 272320
    },
    {
      "name": "validation-of-art",
      "id": "13",
      "status": "passed",
      "duration": 272320
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what i have tried with:

```
jq -r 'unique_by(.Result.name)'
```

and also with `jq 'unique_by(.Result[].name)'`

I am getting an error - `Cannot index array with string "Result"`
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an example which eliminates all but one of the `.Result` objects using `unique_by(.name)`

```
$ jq -M '.Result |= unique_by(.name)' data.json
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "name": "validation-of-art",
      "id": "12",
      "status": "passed",
      "duration": 4740302
    }
  ]
}
```

If this isn't quite what you want you can generalize this easily.  E.g. to keep one object for each unique `{name,id}` you could use

```
$ jq -M '.Result |= unique_by({name, id})' data.json
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "name": "validation-of-art",
      "id": "12",
      "status": "passed",
      "duration": 4740302
    },
    {
      "name": "validation-of-art",
      "id": "13",
      "status": "passed",
      "duration": 272320
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what if I want to loop through the results and do an action, how do I do that?

Comment: @gdubs can you be more specific?  What part of the results do you care about and what sort of action do you mean?  If you mean more json transformations you can simply add more filters to your jq expression.  If you mean external processing then you'll probably need another program or script to do that for you and if it isn't able to process json you may have to do a little more on the jq side to adapt the output into something it can consume.